# A view for a game without a layout

Tags: android, layout, view

I'm at the beginning of my development for my game and I have a basic question.

Is the layout necessary for displaying a view?

I have the method which allows me to make the toolbar disappear and set the view screen wide, but it seems a bit useless to do so.
Besides in the snake sample provided in the sdk, the views are merged without a layout.

So, which one is the best practice.
And if it's the layout-less solution, how to do for a unique view to display?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am as new as you are too, but as far as I have searched and learned online and with a few examples, all I can say is, NO. Game programming does not need any xml layouts. For developing a game, you need to first create a good basic framework. All the views, sprites, actions, audio, etc... is created at background.

[This](http://www.kilobolt.com/game-development-tutorial.html) is a very nice tutorial to start with.

Comment: I've already seen the tutorial you mention, but the guy does not use the Android Framework in his dev.
I don't know if it's a good or bad idea (maybe someone more experienced could answer) but this method will require slightly more work when you'll have to port your app to an android device...Well, I believe so at least.

Comment: Start with [this](http://www.kilobolt.com/day-5-the-android-game-framework-part-i.html). If you know the basics of Java and Android, you can skip the basic tutorial. It also has the complete Android project source, but it's better if you go step by step.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on lots of things, but yes you don't need to create an **XML** layout. Pay attention to the word **XML**. You can create a custom class which extends `SurfaceView` and work in cooperate with `Thread` to do the update. So in this case you just need to set your `Activity`'s `Content View` to this subclass of `SurfaceView`. But by using `SurfaceView` you have a raw of context which means you should do everything from stratch, e.g you should implement your own button.

Beside this it depends on the engine/framework you use too. But for `SurfaceView/Canvas API` the  lines I mentioned above is valid.